# The iPhone “phone” doesn’t have the provisioning profile with which the application was signed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, provisioning

I have tried everything to fix this provision problem and nothing is working. I've reformated my Mac, reinstalled the iPhone, I've also dragged the provisions (developer and distribution) onto the Organizer, iTunes, and Xcode.

In iTunes people say to drag the provisions to the iPhone icon but that doesn't work; it's only able to go under Library (it shows a blue rectangle for me to drop it there). I just have a newly created dummy app with a 57x57 icon. I've also setup the project with the distribution thing with its distribution provision. When I build I get this:

```
The iPhone “myphone” doesn’t have the provisioning profile with which the application was signed.

Click “Install and Run” to install the provisioning profile “distribution” on “myphone” and continue running “helloworld.app”.
```

and it has a button "install and run" ive clicked on that hundreths of times and nothing.

in orgranizer I see a tab called Console. I've cleared it and rebuild the app and there is some output that I dont understand. I'm thinking its my problem whats it mean?

```
Fri Mar 26 11:22:19 unknown misagent[215] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
Fri Mar 26 11:22:19 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00808600 install_embedded_profile: Skipping the installation of the embedded profile
Fri Mar 26 11:22:20 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00808600 verify_executable: Could not validate signature: e8008015
Fri Mar 26 11:22:20 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00808600 preflight_application_install: Could not verify /var/tmp/install_staging.NEb61T/helloworld.app/helloworld
Fri Mar 26 11:22:20 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00808600 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Fri Mar 26 11:22:20 unknown mobile_installation_proxy[219] <Error>: handle_install: Installation failed
Fri Mar 26 11:22:20 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00808600 handle_install: API failed
Fri Mar 26 11:22:20 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00808600 send_message: failed to send mach message of 64 bytes: 10000003
Fri Mar 26 11:22:20 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00808600 send_error: Could not send error response to client
Fri Mar 26 11:22:42 unknown misagent[231] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
Fri Mar 26 11:22:43 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00809800 install_embedded_profile: Skipping the installation of the embedded profile
Fri Mar 26 11:22:43 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00809800 verify_executable: Could not validate signature: e8008015
Fri Mar 26 11:22:43 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00809800 preflight_application_install: Could not verify /var/tmp/install_staging.6M55Ay/helloworld.app/helloworld
Fri Mar 26 11:22:43 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00809800 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Fri Mar 26 11:22:43 unknown mobile_installation_proxy[235] <Error>: handle_install: Installation failed
Fri Mar 26 11:22:43 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00809800 handle_install: API failed
Fri Mar 26 11:22:43 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00809800 send_message: failed to send mach message of 64 bytes: 10000003
Fri Mar 26 11:22:43 unknown mobile_installationd[206] <Error>: 00809800 send_error: Could not send error response to client
```

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the problem.

what i did was recreate a dummy project and named the project sample.
then i created a new development and distribution provision and called it sample.
i deleted all the provisions i had currently on my system and added the new ones by selecting both files and dragging it over into the xcode organiser. i also deleted the provision on my iphone by going to settings -> general -> profile -> clicked on remove. then i selected in xcode build -> build and it was successfull. what i was doing was i was a clicking on build and run and whenever i do that i get this error posted above.  but when i do a regular build with the device selected in xcode it is 100% sucessfull with no errors. i had to try it in itunes connect to see if the app is sucessfull and i did an upload and it worked!. i cant believe it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Provision profile under Project Settings matches the profiles installed on the iPhone.

Project Settings

[Project 201CavTouch201D Info http://img.skitch.com/20100326-ei2k9yha5yknrrcq4hsfgyet7f.preview.jpg](http://skitch.com/jordanx/n59bm/project-avtouch-info)

For iPhone
Check the Organizer menu options from the Window Menu of Xcode.

Be sure they match.

Comment: in organizor under the device i have the development provision. the distribution provision - i wasnt able to add. under provision profiles i have one for development and one for distribution. would you like a screen shot? how to i check if they match what do i look for in organizor?

Comment: ps: in the project settings page do i select the distribution provision for code signing identity or "any iphone os device"  ?

Comment: How check your iPhone, Settings-General-Profiles. What provisioning profiles are listed? Try deleting the profiles and syncing again.

If that doesn't work. Go http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action and follow the instructions.